# Click hyperlink from website table using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate-desktop

Need to click the link from webpage which is in table, table is inside the frame tag. There are multiple frames on the webpage, and I can get the frame that I want by using the "id=mainFrame", but unable to click the link. I tried using the Javascript in the PowerAutomate, but didnt work. Any leads will be helpful.

```
//itrate each frame and find 'main' frame for deal selection
for (int i = 1; i < window.frames['frames'].length; i++) 
{
    ///console.log(window.frames['frames'][i].frameElement.id);
    if (  window.frames['frames'][i].name == 'main' && window.frames['frames'][i].frameElement.id == 'mainFrame')
    {
        var ifrm = window.frames['frames'][i];
        //itrate each table row in deal list and click the link
        for (int j=1; j<=ifrm.document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].querySelectorAll("tr").length-1; j++)
        {
            if(ifrm.document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].querySelectorAll("tr")[j].querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText == %sDealName% && ifrm.document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].querySelectorAll("tr")[j].querySelectorAll("td")[2].innerText == %sSeriesName%)
            {
                window.frames['frames'][i].document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].querySelectorAll("tr")[j].querySelectorAll("td")[2].querySelectorAll("a")[0].click()
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

[image] [image]